# Latitude / Longitude MySQL Query Producing an Error (#1064)

Tags: php, mysql, trigonometry

I am testing code that I have found on StackOverflow that uses lat / long to get rows based on distance in miles.  All the questions and answers that use this method don't address the issue I am having when I run this query in my database.

```
SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('42.3581') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( long ) - radians('-71.0636') ) + sin( radians('42.3581') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM geo_top_cities HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```

I am getting an error that says:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long ) - radians('-71.0636') ) + sin( radians('42.3581') ) * sin( radians( lat )' at line 1
```

I have tried using single quotes around the lat and long coordinates, no single quotes, etc.  I even tried removing the spaces in the parenthesis which did not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`long` is a [`reserved keyword`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) in MySQL. You need to surround it in backticks !

Comment: I had a feeling it was something that obvious.  Thank you!